# Cron job not saving

Tags: cron

I'm trying to write a very basic cron job but it doesn't seem to be saving.  Here's what I've done:

1) `crontab -e`

This opens up a file with vim.

2)

```
#!usr/bin/env python

0 23 * * 0 ~/Desktop/SquashScraper/helpfulFunctions.py
```

3) `:wq`

4) crontab -l

Nothing shows up and I get this message:

```
crontab: no crontab for ben
```

I've looked around and most people with similar issues had editor problems.  My crontab opens correctly with vim, so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Any idea why this might not be working / saving properly?

Thanks,
bclayman

Edit to include: 
[image]

Comment: http://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2006-November/msg03509.html

Comment: @PersianGulf I just looked at the link you posted.  I looked into my /etc folder but I don't have cron.d or cron.daily within it :(

Comment: When you create a job, crontab create a tmp file in /tmp , you can cp manually in your target dir.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "you can cp manually in your target dir"

Comment: target dir is a manullay and dirty way, But it solves your problem, `crontab -e`  should create a file for you, and you can copy it to `/etc/cron.d/`

Comment: @PersianGulf but I don't have cron.d within /etc :(

Comment: When you say `crontab -e`, does the editor open with an empty file? so you type in all the lines that you show in step 2?  It doesn't make sense to have a "she-bang" line (`#!…`) in your crontab file; `crontab -e` might be rejecting your edit as invalid because of it.  (Are you sure you're not getting an error message when you do the `:wq` out of `crontab -e`?)  Try leaving that out the `#!` line, typing only the `0 23 …` line, and see what happens.  … … … … … …  P.S. The `helpfulFunctions.py` file should, of course, begin with `#!usr/bin/env python`.

Comment: @G-Man I just left out the "she-bang" and I get "crontab: no crontab for ben - using an empty one
crontab: "/usr/bin/vi" exited with status 1".  Then I run "crontab -l" and get "crontab: no crontab for ben"

Comment: Have you tried to edit it using nano? Might be vi has some sort of issue saving.

Comment: What's the name of the file? While you are in the editor you should be able to see which file you are editing.

Comment: What you're doing looks correct. (The `#!usr/bin/env python` line has no effect, you need to put that at the top of your script, but all the crons I've seen treat lines beginning with `#` as a comment line, so that's not your problem.) What OS/distribution are you running this on? Do you have root access to investigate?

Comment: @kasperd the name of the file is "/tmp/crontab.07Uv1X75AL"

Comment: @Gilles This is on a Mac running OS X Yosemite and yeah, I have root access

Comment: @bclayman The path looks fine, I don't think there is any problem with that. However the message `crontab: "/usr/bin/vi" exited with status 1` sounds like it might explain the problem. It sounds sensible for cron to discard all changes if the editor exists with a non-zero status. So my next question is, why does `vi` exit with status 1? What does `file /usr/bin/vi` say?

Comment: @kasperd just edited original post to include screenshot of that file.  it looks like a bunch of nonsense tho :(

Comment: @bclayman On Ubuntu it appears that cron does discard any changes made if the editor exists with status 1. So I am now almost certain that error message is part of the explanation.

Comment: @bclayman Doesn't OS X have a `file` command? I can tell from the screenshot that it looks like an executable, so I don't think we will learn anymore from the output of `file`. Your problem is that `vi` is somehow not working like it is supposed to. But we don't know what is wrong with your `vi`. Do you get the same error message if you simply edit a file using `vi` directly from the command line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24811/discussion-between-bclayman-and-kasperd).

Comment: @kasperd please see above :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For some reason `/usr/bin/vi` is not working correctly on your machine as you can tell from the error message:

```
crontab: "/usr/bin/vi" exited with status 1
```

What happened there is that when you leave `vi` it is producing an error code. When `crontab` sees that `vi` exited with an error code, it will not trust the contents of the file `vi` was editing and simply doesn't make any changes to your crontab.

You can try to investigate further why `vi` is not working, or if you prefer to, you can use a completely different editor. For example if you prefer to use `vim`, you can type:

```
EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim crontab -e
```

Alternatively you can keep the "official" version of your crontab under your home directory. Then edit the version under your home directory and finally install it using:

```
crontab filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your system, user crontabs are saved in `/var/spool/cron/`. Check you have this directory. Also the crontab program is setuid so you cannot read other people's crontabs, so check this (-rw**s**...):

```
$ ls -l /bin/crontab
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 57536 Sep 18  2014 /bin/crontab
```

Your vim seems to exit with an error code. Try putting your entry in a file "myfile" and then using `crontab myfile` to install it. You may get more meaningful error messages.

Also, to run crontab you may need the file `/etc/cron.deny` to exist (it is usually empty). If it doesnt I get an error message.

Your #! line will not work, as @G-Man said in the comments. You need something like

```
0 23 * * 0 python ~/Desktop/SquashScraper/helpfulFunctions.py
```

Comment: I looked within /var/spool and I don't have a cron folder :( My crontab folder looks like this: -rwsr-xr-x     1 root   wheel     35040 Sep  9  2014 crontab.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I won't give an answer to the original question here, but if you're trying to schedule tasks for *Mac OS 10.9+* with `cron`, **you're doing it wrong**: `crontab` is deprecated. You should use `launchctl` with `launchd` ([man page here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html)) instead.

`launchd`/`launchctl` works with `.plist` files that describe each task, similar to the way you'd use `systemd`/`systemctl` with `.service` files. 
It may be unsettling at first, but it's actually easy to use, although it's less convenient than using `cron` with a single `crontab -e`.

Fortunately, there's a lot of GUI softwares available to manage `launchd` tasks easily. My personal favorite is [**Launch Control**](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) by soma-zone. It's 10$ but you can download and use their software without limitation.

---

Anyway, in your case, here's what your `~/Library/LaunchAgents/HelpfulFunctionsJob.plist` file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>HelpfulFunctions.job</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/bclayman/Desktop/SquashScraper/helpfulFunctions.py</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>23</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>Weekday</key>
        <integer>7</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Just make sure to change `<string>/Users/bclayman/Desktop/SquashScraper/helpfulFunctions.py</string>` to your actual path, and then, to load the job:

```
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/HelpfulFunctionsJob.plist
```